# How to create RESTful service with GlassFish 4?

Tags: java, .net, rest, glassfish

I've come from a C#.NET development, have developed and implemented RESTful services in Visual Studio with WCF hosted on IIS, but now I need guidance on one of my project requirement, to develop RESTful service with GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 (not Oracle GlassFish), found here: 
https://glassfish.java.net/download.html

I have no idea about Java and GlassFish, so if any tutorial post or video provided will be highly appreciated. What all sorts of application software do I need to install and what will be the development environment? I mean every step involved in the process of developing in GlassFish.

Also is there any way to develop RESTful service in C#.net and deploy on GlassFish 4?

Answer (score 0):

I've done REST web service with C# and with Java and, basically, both technologies are quite similar. I would recommend you to spend some time learning the servlets, understanding then and with your knowledge of web services you will find no problems to implement your service.

Additionally, yopu could also take a look to the Java technologies specifically implemented for REST like "JAX-RS: Java API for RESTful Web Services" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services). This may help you, but I would begin with the basics of a servlet and the servlet container (GlassFish).